# internal error occurred during resetting password

Tags: gack, reset-password

First of all, I understand that this might not be the correct platform to ask such question, but I am looking for support.So, here I go

I am trying to reset password for my developer org. When I click on reset password link sent by salesforce to my mail account, I see a screen with security question. I answer it and then I see below image

[image]

I have contacted Salesforce support and as per suggestion I have tried it with deleting cookies, installing new browser(FireFox) for the first time in my laptop and 
also with incognito window, but I continue face same issue.

Comment: Are these sandboxes using the same instance?

Comment: I am trying with my own trailhead sandbox. These are not different sandboxes

Comment: I am still facing this issue. Anyone has any ideas??